# Sending code from Sublime Text 3 to R Terminal or SublimeREPL

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I realise there are a few threads that already exist with regards to the second half of my question, but they don't seem to address the problem.

I am using R-Box, SendText, and SendCode to send lines of code from Sublime Text 3 to the R-GUI. However, I prefer working in Rterm rather than the GUI. Is there a way to modify settings in any of the three sublime text packages to send code to Rterm.exe instead?

In the mean time, I recently got a new laptop and can't seem to get Sublime Text 3 to send code to SublimeREPL properly. It decides to send the occasional line, but will not send some for no reason. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, interesting question. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made Sublime/R-Box/SendCode work with Rterm by changing the settings in the RGui to **SDI**.

In RGui > Gui Settings > Select "SDI" > Click on "Save" > Close R Gui (this will show a warning)

Reopen R Gui to check that it opens Rterm.

In Sublime, working with SendCode/R-Box then will open the Rterm.

Use the standard settings in SendCode (In Sublime: Crtl+Alt+P > SendCode: Choose Program > Select "R Gui"), it works with R Term.

Note: You must open Rterm manually before using it from Sublime.

Let me know, please, if that worked for you.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a treat, and was so much simpler than what I kept on trying and failing to achieve.